# App crashes pubnub subscribe after build apk in Flutter

Tags: java, android, ios, flutter

I am using flutter_pubnub: ^0.2.0

Crashlytics error log

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: throw with null exception
at com.pubnub.api.models.server.SubscribeMetadata.getTimetoken(SubscribeMetadata.java:3)
at com.pubnub.api.managers.SubscriptionManager$5.a(SubscriptionManager.java:201)
at com.pubnub.api.managers.SubscriptionManager$5.a(SubscriptionManager.java:2)
at com.pubnub.api.endpoints.Endpoint$1.a(Endpoint.java:45)
at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:37)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

In debug mode working correctly

Comment: Please submit this to [PubNub Support](https://support.pubnub.com) with code, sub-key and this error log and the like to this post.

Comment: Issue fixed in latest release https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_pubnub issue solved